# Access Java Melody data

Tags: java, monitoring

Is there anyway I can access the java melody data from within my application to create my own custom charts and statistics?

Comment: I think I just found the answer http://code.google.com/p/javamelody/wiki/ExternalAPI

Anyway leaving this question unedited to help anyone else who might across the same problem.